# How do I introduce this relative clause clearly?

Tags: relative-clauses

> As we shall see later on, there are pairs of genes ______ neither gene
>   dominates but each lessens the effects of the other.

Which of the following makes the most sense to create the relative clause?
-that
-whose
-in which
-whom
-of which

Comment: Not too complicated on the face: *in which* seems to work best, as you are referring to a relationship between members within the pair.

Comment: I agree with  ScotM.

Answer (score 1):

None of "that", "whose" or "whom" fits at all - neither in terms of the meaning nor in forming a grammatical sentence.

That just leaves "in which" or "of which".  Since it neither one of the pair we are referring to, then "in which" makes more sense.  "of which" implies the pair as a whole.